# __proto__ inside JavaScript function prototype property

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

Imagine simple function:

```
function Person();
```

I know that `Person` has `__proto__` property that references to Function.prototype.

I also know that `Person` has `prototype` property. When I write:
`function Person() {}`, a new prototype object is automatically created:

```
Person.prototype = { constructor: Person };
```

but inside Person.prototype block, I also have `__proto__`, so what is this `__proto__`, when is it created, who creates it?

I may know that it's `Object`'s prototype but is it always so?

Comment: All constructors have prototype chains that drill down to `Function.prototype`, and all instances of objects created by these constructors have prototype chains that drill down to `Object.prototype`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: Also, `__proto__` is a pseudo-property (technically a getter/setter on `Object.prototype`) exposing the internal `[[Prototype]]` object. So even `{}` (an "empty" object) has a `__proto__` property...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but prototypes have their prototypes which can have their prototypes which can have their prototypes and so on until `null`. Based on your question you may know it's called prototype chain, if not now you know :) You can read in more detail about it on [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).